# Unhide all sheets of a spreadsheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I would like to activate all hiden sheets by using google app script.

I tried:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(„xxx“ &&“yyy“).activate ();
```

And i try it also for every sheet separate

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation:

I assume you mean you want to **unhide** **all** the sheets.

- You can use [showSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showSheet()) for **every** sheet since this function has no effect on a sheet that is already visible.
- Use [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) to get all the sheets and then [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to unhide every sheet in the spreadsheet file.

### Solution:

```
function unhideAllSheets() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(sh=>sh.showSheet()); 
}
```